# syncfusion ej chart redraw [n] undefined

Tags: charts, refresh, syncfusion, redraw

I am using ASP MVC and I have a ej chart built in script, and I need to refresh its content:

my chart is built like this:

```
var modelSummaryList = getMySummaryModel();
        var summaryChartDataManager = ej.DataManager(($scope.FirstLoad && IsCurrentUserDpiUser()) ? null : modelSummaryList);
        jQuery("#MySummaryChart").ejChart({
            range: { min: summaryChartDataManager == null ? -1 : summaryChartDataManager.ChartMin, max: summaryChartDataManager == null ? 1 : summaryChartDataManager.ChartMax },

            series: [{
                name: "MTM",
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "#point.x#: #point.y# #series.name#"
                },
                dataSource: summaryChartDataManager,
                xName: "CtpyShort",
                yName: "MTM"
            }, {
                name: "Threshold",
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "#point.x#: #point.y# #series.name#"
                },
                dataSource: summaryChartDataManager,
                xName: "CtpyShort",
                yName: "Threshold"
            }, {
                name: "My Held/(Posted)",
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "#point.x#: #point.y# #series.name#"
                },
                dataSource: summaryChartDataManager,
                xName: "CtpyShort",
                yName: "Held"
            }],
            type: 'column',
        });
```

which is working good, but upon filter and change of data, I need to redraw the chart so I did this:

```
$scope.RefreshChart = function (data) {
        var chart = $("#MySummaryChart").ejChart("instance");
        chart.model.range.min = data.MyTradeSummaryVM.ChartMin;
        chart.model.range.max = data.MyTradeSummaryVM.ChartMax;
        for (var s = 0; s <= chart.model.series.length - 1; s++) {
            var pts = IsCurrentUserDpiUser() ? $.grep(data.MyTradeSummaryVM, function (item) {
                return item.ClientID == localStorage.getItem("MyPosting_client_sticky");
            }) : data.MyTradeSummaryVM;
            chart.model.series[s].points = [];

            for (var p = 0; p <= pts.length - 1; p++) {

                var newPt = new Object();

                newPt.x = pts[p].CtpyShort;

                if (chart.model.series[s].name == "MTM")
                    newPt.y = pts[p].MTM;
                else if (chart.model.series[s].name == "Threshold")
                    newPt.y = pts[p].Threshold;
                else if (chart.model.series[s].name == "My Held/(Posted)")
                    newPt.y = pts[p].Held;

                newPt.visible = true;
                chart.model.series[s].points.push(newPt);

            }
        }
        chart.redraw();

    };
```

which throws the error **TypeError: n[0] is undefined** on the chart.redraw() line, and I am stumped. Please note that the RefreshChart() works if I build the chart via cshtml and not javascript like this:

```
@(Html.EJ().Chart("MySummaryChart")
                    .PrimaryXAxis(pr => pr.Title(tl => tl.Text("")))
                    .PrimaryYAxis(pr => pr.Range(ra => ra.Max(Model.ChartMax).Min(Model.ChartMin)).Title(tl => tl.Text("")))
                    .CommonSeriesOptions(cr => cr.Type(SeriesType.Column).EnableAnimation(true).Marker(mr => mr.DataLabel(dt => dt.Visible(true).EnableContrastColor(true)))
                    .Tooltip(tt => tt.Visible(true).Format("#point.x# : #point.y# #series.name# ")))
                    .Series(sr =>
                    {
                       .
.
.

                    })

                    .Load("loadTheme")
                    .IsResponsive(true)
                    .Size(sz => sz.Height("400"))
                    .Legend(lg => { lg.Visible(true).Position(LegendPosition.Bottom); }))
```

but I am opting to use JS coz I need to handle null and firstload(meaning no data should appear on the chart upon first load, and unless user picks a client(filter), no data should be loaded. Which I cant seem to make it work if via html, I couldn't erase the chart xaxisregions label along with other data, the only things erased are the main Y axis points but not labels.

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed the reported scenario. We would like to you know that, when the data for chart is bind using **dataSource**, then while refreshing the chart with new data, you need to bind the data to **series.dataSource** property not to **series.points**, so that only chart will refresh properly. We have prepared a sample with respect the above scenario. Find the code snippet to achieve this requirement.

```
<input type="button" id="refreshChart" onclick="refresh()" value="Refresh Chart" />

function refresh(sender) {
    var chart = $("#MySummaryChart").ejChart("instance");
    for (var s = 0; s <= chart.model.series.length - 1; s++) {
        //Obtained random data,
        var pts = GetData().data;
        var newPt = [];
        for (var p = 0; p <= pts.length - 1; p++) {
            if (chart.model.series[s].name == "MTM")
                newPt.push({ "CtpyShort": pts[p].CtpyShort, "MTM": pts[p].MTM });
            else if (chart.model.series[s].name == "Threshold")
                newPt.push({ "CtpyShort": pts[p].CtpyShort, "Threshold": pts[p].Threshold });
            else if (chart.model.series[s].name == "My Held/(Posted)")
                newPt.push({ "CtpyShort": pts[p].CtpyShort, "Held": pts[p].Held });
        }
        //Assign the updated data to dataSource property
        chart.model.series[s].dataSource = newPt;
    }
    chart.redraw();
}
```

In the above code in a button click event, we have refreshed the chart data. Here you need to assign the **x value** to **CtpyShort** and **y values** of three series to **MTM**, **Threshold** and **Held**, since we have mapped these properties while rendering the chart initially.

Screenshot before updating data:
[image]

Screenshot after updating data:
[image]

Sample for reference can be find from below link.

[Sample Link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/194880/ze/chartSample2053456255)

If you face still any concern, kindly revert us by modifying the above sample with respect to your scenario or provide your sample with replication steps which will helpful in further analysis and provide you the solution sooner.

Thanks,
Dharani.

Comment: this is working om loading chart with data, but not refreshing chart if there is no data. the chart is still there with the previous data. It should be blank. How to solve this? tnx